# How can I use document.createElement DOM in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, jsdom

I'm new in programming and currently learning node.js and express.js

I have a form for user to contact me when submitted it should open windows mail app, in javascript I can just use `document.createElement('a')`

but when I use it on node.js it says `'document' is not defined` or `createElement is not a function`

I've tried to use jsdom

Here's the js code:

```
app.post('/contact-me', function(req, res) {
let name = req.body.userName
let email = req.body.userEmail
let phone = req.body.userPhoneNumber
let subject = req.body.userSubject
let message = req.body.userMessage
let form = req.body.contact /
let contact = {
    name,
    email,
    phone,
    subject,
    message
}

let openMail = new JSDOM(contact) //I've also tried let openMail = new JSDOM(form)
let myEmail = "dev@mail.com"

let a = openMail.window.document.createElement('a')
a.href = `mailto:${myEmail}?subject=${subject}&body=Hello, my name is ${name}, ${subject}, ${message}`
a.click()
})`
```

Form opening tag: `<form class="form-container" action="/contact" method="POST" name="contact">`

But it says:

```
Error: Not implemented: navigation (except hash changes)
at module.exports (D:\folder\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\browser\not-implemented.js:9:17)      
at navigateFetch (D:\folder\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\window\navigation.js:77:3)      
at exports.navigate (D:\folder\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\window\navigation.js:55:3)   
at Timeout._onTimeout (D:\folder\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\nodes\HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils-impl.js:81:7)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) undefined
```

Do node.js have different code or I have to do something before using DOM?

Comment: generally, you would use nodemailer to send your email

Comment: There is no DOM in NodeJS. The DOM is not part of the JavaScript language. It's part of the browser API. NodeJS has its own API

Comment: `new JSDOM()` takes a string: `const dom = new JSDOM(\`<!DOCTYPE html><p>Hello world</p>\`);`. See: [JSDOM](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom).

Comment: It appears to be telling you that jsdom can’t navigate to a mailto: link (not surprising, it has no concept of how to handle that uri type). I don’t think your approach is at all correct, you need some sort of SMTP/outbound mail handler, I’d look on ‘npm’ for possibles.

Comment: I have found a module called openurl but when I click submit it open file explorer instead of windows email app, there's a command in the module that looks like this: `case 'win32': command = "explorer.exe"` I'm now trying to find a way to execute the email app but I can't found it

Comment: Do you want a link on your webpage that will open a mail app? If so, why use nodejs (server-side) and not simply HTML (client-side)?

Comment: You need to return client side javascript as an HTML response.